# Spring MVC Before Calling Url Method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have questoion about Spring MVC Controller. I want to write a method in HomeController, this method will run automatically every calling in HomeController's other methods before the called method run. First my method will run and after other calling method will run. How can i do that ?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Your scenario can be implemented via AOP. You could take a look at spring-aop and AspectJ.

Comment: I think AOP is a little too complicated for such a scenario. I see two options depending on what you want to do in the method that is called a each request : if you want to add an attribute in the model, just create a method annoted with `@ModelAttribute` in `HomeController`. If you want to do something else, you should use the `preHandle()`method of an `HandlerInterceptor`. That being said, if you want to do more complex things, AOP might be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search AOP before advice. You need to write "Spring Bean Configuration File"

After you need to call that xml file with annotation